# Can I use 'could' instead of 'might' in this unreal situation?

Tags: can-could, can-may

Are **might** and **could** exchangeable in this *unreal situation*?

> If I were in Tom's position, I think I ***might*** look for another job.

Comment: What makes you think they are or are not? What steps have you taken to try to answer the question before asking here? Please add these vital details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to use "might" in this context.

The alternative would probably be "would" rather than "could". Use of "could" implies you would only be able to look for another job if you started from Tom's position.

Comment: Or that Tom is currently too emotionally distraught to look for another job, and if the speaker were in his position he wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: True. Good spot.